# HtmlSanitizationLibrary with white list possible?

Tags: .net, xss

In the  latest  version of HtmlSanitizationLibrary assembly  downloadable with AntiXSS Library v4.0 ,

the function  GetSafeHtml() replaces   each

```
         <p> and </p> tags  by  \r\n <p>  or  \r\n </p>  .
```

This known bug is reported on

http://wpl.codeplex.com/discussions/82446

but my question is not this.

Can i Sanitize HTML based on white list of tags using  HtmlSanitizationLibrary

Comment: -1 It's unclear what the question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear.

Did you mean "Does AntiXSS use a whitelist to sanitize HTML?" ? Then the answer is yes.

Did you mean "Can I specify my own whitelist to be used by AntiXSS?" ? Then the answer is no, as far as I can tell (at least it's not documented anywhere). At any rate, specifying your own whitelist is kind of pointless - the whole point of AntiXSS is that it handles the whitelist for you, because such a whitelist can be quite tricky to get right.

Also see [Why use Microsoft AntiXSS library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022289/why-use-microsoft-antixss-library) ; Steven's answer addresses a similar question.

Comment: there is dll  called HtmlSanitizationLibrary.dll .it has a function GetSafeHtml()  .I am talking about it

Comment: @user444569: Yes, you wrote that in your question, but that does not make it any clearer. So, what is your question?

Comment: My question is that ,can i configure the list of allowed tags when i use HtmlSanitizationLibrary?

Comment: @user444569: As I wrote in my answer: No, apparently you cannot configure the list of allowed tags, and it would be kind of pointless.