# How to properly sanitize content with AntiXss Library?

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, xss, antixsslibrary

I have a simple forums application, when someone posts any content, i do:

```
post.Content = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtml(post.Content);
```

Now, i am not sure if i am doing something wrong, or what is going on, but it does not allow almost no html. Even simple `<b></b>` is too much for it. So i guess that tool is totally useless.

Now my question: Can anyone tell me how should i sanitize my users inputs so that they can post some images(`<img>` tags) and use bold emphasis etc?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to strip out the dangerous html tags? Maybe you are looking for `post.Content = Encoder.HtmlEncode("<b>test</b>");`

Comment: Yes i want to strip out the dangerous tags. `.HtmlEncode` encodes all the tags, so `<b>` or `<img>` won't work...

Comment: What do you mean "won't work"? If you display `&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/&gt;` in a browser, the browser will make `test` bold. Remember that browsers display `<b>test</b>` and `&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/&gt;` the same way. If you want to strip out some html tags but keep some others? I think that's a risky thing to do.

Comment: @RayCheng you're talking crazy talk.

Comment: @RayCheng If i give the browser `&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/&gt;` as output, it will display `<b>test</b>`, not make the `test` string bold. That why is it made for. :)

Answer (score 6):

It seems that many people find the sanitizer [rather useless](https://wpl.codeplex.com/releases/view/80289#ReviewsAnchor). Instead of using the sanitizer, just encode everything, and decode safe parts back:

```cs
private static readonly IEnumerable<string> WhitelistedTags =
    new[] { "<b>", "</b>", "<i>", "</i>" };

private static readonly (string Encoded, string Decoded)[] DecodingPairs =
    WhitelistedTags
    .Select(tag => (Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(tag), tag))
    .ToArray();

public static string Sanitize(string html)
{
    // Encode the whole thing
    var safeHtml = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(html);
    var builder = new StringBuilder(safeHtml);

    // Decode the safe parts
    foreach (var (encodedTag, decodedTag) in DecodingPairs)
    {
        builder.Replace(encodedTag, decodedTag);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Please note that it's nearly impossible to safely decode an **IMG** tag, since there are really simple ways for an attacker to abuse this tag. Examples:

```
<IMG SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');">

<IMG SRC=&#106;&#97;&#118;&#97;&#115;&#99;&#114;&#105;&#112;&#116;&#58;&#97;&#108;&#101;&#114;&#116;&#40;&#39;&#88;&#83;&#83;&#39;&#41;>
```

Take a look here for more a thorough [XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Yes, thank you, but i am looking for some already made solutions, so i can use them. I think it will be safer and will save me some time. It's sad that sanitizer does not work, it was my best option so far...

Comment: The line `safeHtml.Replace(encodedTag,decodedTag);` doesn't do anything as the result of the `Replace` method is lost?

Comment: Hi @Zesty, that code change has no effect. A `StringBuilder`'s `Replace` method just returns a reference to itself. I refactored the code a bit though to make it more readable. I also tested the code; it does what it is intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/) best describes the issues with the Anti XSS library and provides a good work around that whitelists a set of tags and attributes.

I'm using this solution in my project and it seems to work great.

Answer (score -1):

There is a quite simple way to block the threat by just getting rid of the "dangerous" tags.

```
string SanitizeHtml(string html)
{
        html = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);

        List<string> blackListedTags = new List<string>() 
        {
                "body", "script", "iframe", "form", "object", "embed", "link", "head", "meta" 
        };

        foreach (string tag in blackListedTags) { 
            html = Regex.Replace(html, "<" + tag, "<p", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
            html = Regex.Replace(html, "</" + tag, "</p", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }

        return html;
}
```

With this the user will still see what is within the dangerous script, but it won't harm anything.

Comment: I do not recommend using blacklisting, as done in this answer, because it is almost impossible to do this in a way that can't be abused by a hacker. Just take a look at [how many ways there are to abuse images](https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet) to inject scripts.