# Parameterized queries are the only method to avoid sql injection?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a method (specially using ASP.net tools) to avoid sql injection other than parameterized queries?

Comment: what's wrong with parameterized queries?

Comment: Look at using an ORM I suppose... But even those will just do it for you...

Comment: There is a dll antixssLibrary available you should be using that

Comment: here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022289/why-use-microsoft-antixss-library

Comment: @krshekhar, that´s what I was looking for, an ASP.net tool, in this case the Anti XSS Library, to filter my user inputs. Although it seems to be pretty useful for more than just SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. Other than parameterized queries, you should also consider these:

1. Using stored procedures
2. Using a limited access account to connect to the database (not admin level)
3. Encrypt the ConnectionString and other sensitive data
4. Set debug=false (in customError) to minimize the information in the event of error

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

one of the simplest method is what I call sanitization. Just `Replace( vsInputString, "'", "''")` while constructing the SQL statement:

```
Dim vsSQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM table01 WHERE myField = '" & Replace(vsFormTextInput, "'", "''" ) & "';"
```

will also help stop SQL injection.