# How to use Microsoft AntiXss 4.x?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, xss, antixsslibrary

I want to use the new version of the [AntiXss](https://wpl.codeplex.com/) library from Microsoft. I downloaded it from the Nuget package but I'm not sure where should I go from here. No documentation is provided for the library and all the articles I find on the Web are old. Since a lot has changed and pretty much everything I want to use is marked as deprecated in the library itself, I wonder which is the best way to use this library?

- Should I make it my default encoder?
- Should I modify all the views to use
  `Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.HtmlEncode()` and such?
- Both maybe?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326339/992425) to "Why use Microsoft AntiXSS library?" for a hint to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Security.AntiXss;

string a = AntiXssEncoder.XmlAttributeEncode(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss being deprecated, Microsoft advises to use Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder instead. It's a static class inside the same library as the AntiXss class.